# Clon EA-elements within the model

Tags: enterprise-architect

Can I clon a class diagram (with classes) to another package within the same model?

Moving the elements is easy, simply drag and drop, copying to another model (EAP file) also, but I could not find a way to actually clon some elements within the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual elements can be cloned within one diagram or from one diagram to another using Copy - Paste as New (Ctrl-C - Shift-Ctrl-V); they can also be copied in the project browser using Copy Element(s) from Clipboard - Paste Element(s) from Clipboard (Ctrl-C - Ctrl-V).

A diagram can be copied in the project browser, but this does not clone the diagram's contents.

Copying a package in the project browser does clone all its contents (Ctrl-C - Ctrl-V).

So in order to achieve a complete clone of a diagram and its contents, simply place them all in the same package and copy / paste that.